# Visual Studio Solution with API and SPA - how to run at the same time

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have a visual studio solution with two projects.  Both projects are using .net framework 4.7.2. One project is the SPA (single page app) and the other one is an API web project. In VS, when I start an instance of either project, I am able to use IISExpress through Visual Studio in order to navigate to the local host.  However I cannot run both at the same time in order to access the API through the SPA.  I have done multiple things using IIS Express command line in order to try to get this to work, but to no avail.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Is your issue solved?If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

By default, a single project selection is configured as a startup project but you can set multiple projects as well.To start multiple projects at a time in Visual Studio you could follow the below steps:

1)open visual studio and go to Solution Explorer.

2)Click on properties

[image]

3)By default, a single project is set as the startup project.

[image]

4)Select multiple project options and change project status to start which needs to be started.

[image]

5)Run the application, you will see two projects loading in the browser.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using “Multiple Startup Projects” property of the solution.

Visit the following documentation for step by step instructions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

here is some step to follow:
1. right-click on the solution name.
2. Click on properties.
3. Select 'startup project' under Common properties.
4. Select on multiple startup project.
5. change the action of the two projects from none to 'start' then click apply and ok.
6. After that you can normally run your  project by clicking the start icon.

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019) for referenece.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to figure out how to use IIS Express to run both at the same time.  I edited the application applicationhost.txt in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\IISExpress\config
(redacted personal data with Capital Letters)

```
<sites>
            <site name="API" id="999">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\YYY\YYYZ" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1132:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
        <site name="FrontEnd" id="989">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\XXX\XXXZ" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
        </sites>
```

Comment: if your issue is resolved then mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face similar issues.